# How to fetch tool tip data which comes from java script in chart using selenium?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

Hi I am looking to get Tool tips for this chart - [Donut chart](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/donut-chart/). I tried lot of variation to have tool tips but Its look like its coming from JavaScript so I am not able to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it using Chrome's Dev Tools. Here is how:

1. Right-click on the blue section of the pie chart and select 'Inspect'
2. Right-click on the highlighted element in the 'Elements' tab of DevTools
3. Select `:hover` to apply the hover state
4. you'll see a new div is added below the SVG, something like `*...div class="amcharts-ballon-div"...*`
5. Expand the tree to find the element that contains the text
6. Right-click on that element and select "Copy" > "Copy Selector"
7. Test the selector in the Console tab of DevTools by doing `document.querySelector("paste_selector_here")`

For me, `document.querySelector("#chartdiv > div > div.amcharts-chart-div > div > div")` returned the element in question.

In a test remember to first do a Hover using the [Actions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html) class in the Selenium library.